# How many neurons do we have in our forearm?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology

I am developing a neural interface, getting signals from the forearm and mapping them to hand gestures. The question we have at the moment is what is the upper bound of information bandwidth that we could tap into, meaning if we were to engineer an electrode so small that we could listen to every single neuron in the forearm, how many neurons could we listen to?

Comment: Welcome to SE BIology. Please take the time to take the Tour and find out about this site. After that, the Help on asking questions should be your next call. You need to show that you have done some research for yourself first. What attempts have you made to answer the question yourself?

Comment: Your main contributor to the neuron count are going to be touch sensors. The fingertips are quite dense with them.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the homunculus man, but I haven't succeeded in finding any quantitative estimate whatsoever that supports the representation of the homunculus man as having such a high density of motor and sensory neurons in the hands.